# Can anyone tell me the correct way of writing this query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to show record from a tale where the gallery field value is 1 and 3.
Can anyone help me with this query?

```
$q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE gallery = 1 AND WHERE gallery = 3");
```

Comment: General Advice - Unless it is an example query, don't use the same name for table name and column name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you write:

```
$q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE gallery = 1 OR gallery = 3");
```

Because gallery = 1 AND gallery = 3 is always FALSE!

Alternatively you can write:

```
$q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE gallery IN (1, 3)");
```

IN clause is the same of OR chain

Comment: @user2620338: OK. Have a nice day ;)